# bash not recognizing path of .bashrc PATH modification

Tags: bash, filesystems

I have recently compiled vscode and added the path to the executable to my .bashrc file

I looked online and found the bash command to use, but it gave me the error
bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/aidenk/Desktop/vscodelinux/bin/code-oss: No such file or directory

bash: cd /home/aidenk/Desktop/vscodelinux/bin/
no errors

the directory exists, but bash can't find it but only from .bashrc

I am using KDE plasma on Debian 11

.bashrc

```
> # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    #alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    #alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    #alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi


export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/vscodelinux/bin/code-oss
# I added this part
```

Comment: Not sure about the error as the export line looks correct, but you want `~/Desktop/vscodelinux/bin` instead of `~/Desktop/vscodelinux/bin/code-oss`

Comment: It looks like something is trying to use your entire `PATH` as a file or directory path (but that's not what it is, it's a *list* of directory paths separated by colons). I don't see anything here that'd cause this error. Try adding the command `set -x` before the `export` command, and see what the execution trace looks like as it runs (and especially, what's the command that causes the error).

Comment: i added "set -x" the line before the export and the output is as follows
"+ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/aidenk/Desktop/vscodelinux/bin
+ PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/aidenk/Desktop/vscodelinux/bin"
edit: this is from a newly opened terminal

Comment: Where does the error occur in this trace output? Please edit the question to include the trace and exact error message, in code block format so it's readable.

Comment: @Krayfighter: Please post the exact command which produces the error message. Side note: Your setting of PATH would not work, because tilde expansion does not happen in this case (as you can verify easily by doing a `echo foo:~:bar`.

Comment: replacing the tilde worked, the expansion was the problem, now, new terminals don't immediately error, and the path is as expected, thank you all for your time